# multiple agent strategy assignment with minimal conflict

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have n agents, and each agent has k strategies. Let's say the agents are {X1, X2, ... Xn}, and for one agent Xm we have strategies {Xm_1, Xm_2, ... Xm_k}. Some strategy may have conflict with another strategy. I have a known function f(Xn_i, Xm_j) where the inputs are two strategies from different agent, and the output is a boolean value, true means they have conflict. Now my problem is to design an algorithm to find the best strategy assignment for each agent, so that the number of conflict is minimal. My friend told me to use genetic algorithm to solve it. I am wondering is there any efficient "exact" algorithm to find zero conflict assignment, if possible? Please give me some hints or key words related to such problem, thank you!

clarification:
The "assignment" here means each agent mush choose one strategy from its possible strategy set. For example, if n == 3 and K ==2, this means we have 3 agents, and each agent need to choose one out of its two possible strategies, so the solution space is 2^3 assignments, and we need to find the least conflict strategy assignment.

Comment: If your checking function `f()` is an unpredictable blackbox, there is nothing you can really do except for brute force. If there is some logic in the `f()` it probably can be exploited, but it depends on the structure of `f()` that you don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the special case that each agent has exactly two strategies, the minimization version of this problem is equivalent to [maximum 2-satisfiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Maximum-2-satisfiability), which is NP-hard. Deciding whether there is a conflict-free assignment is polynomial-time, though.

For deciding whether there is a conflict-free assignment where agents have three or more strategies, this problem generalizes the NP-hard problem of 3-coloring a graph.